# Lost user data with app update using CoreData + iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I've recently added iCloud support following [Apple's programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491) and was able to release an update that successfully migrated an existing store to a iCloud-enabled CoreData stack and for a few weeks everything in that update was going great and had no user complaints.

I have since launched a very minor update changing code that does not even touch the CoreData stack, and since then, users updating the app are experiencing their CoreData being completely wiped with the update. I've been going over the programming guides and posts for days now, but I can't seem to figure out what the hell happened.

Does anyone have insight or suggestions to help shed light on what could have happened with an app update to cause data loss?

EDIT: More details: I've verified each archive submitted to the App Store and both are using the Production environment for iCloud containers, using the same ubiquity container, and same entitlements. I'm stumped!

Comment: Did you changed anything in your CoreData schemes?

Comment: If you mean the data model, no, I did not.

Comment: I've experienced similar mysterious data loss with iCloud Core Data sync. When I first implemented iCloud + Core Data with an early iOS 8 version it seemed to work well. However, the sync does not work now with the same implementation. I am migrating away from it and using a sync framework I developed myself.

Comment: This is happening to me too.